# input/output stream on random access file, does close propagate?

Tags: java, file-io

I am creating file input streams/file out streams from a random
access file via the following API:

```
RandomAccessFile.getFD();
FileInputStream(FileDescriptor)
FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor)
```

When I close the file input streams/file out streams, will
the random access file also be closed?

Bye

Comment: Did you consider to use a [channel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#getChannel%28%29)? - Using the file descriptor seems a little "unusual" to me...

Comment: I don't find a constructor for file input stream/file output stream based on channel. And I need to arrive at some objects that implement input stream respectively output stream. Can this be done with channel?

Comment: Get the channel from the RAF and then use the methods of java.nio.channel.Channels.

Comment: Do these methods implement the InputStream and the OutputStream methods? Pitty these protocolls are classes and not interfaces. So it is unlikely that a channel that can represent read and write, implementes both of them (unless Java has suddently multiple class inheritance). I only need selectively to derive one of them from the given RandomAccessFile. Which I can do with the constructors in the question. Question is then whether the close() method on FileInputStream resp. FileOutputStream propagates to RandomAccessFile.

Comment: @CountablyInfinite Obviously you haven't bothered to read the Javadoc for java.nio.channels.Channels. I suggest you do so before any further incorrect theorizing about what is likely and unlikely. The answer is already there.

Comment: If you are 100% sure, then please post an answer. So that I can vote it up, and eventually mark it. Please note that my question is solely about what happens with RandomAccessFile when I perform FileInputStream.close() respectively FileOutputStream.close(). If I look at the oracle source code I see that some reference counting for the file descriptor is involved... But its difficult to figure out what it does.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.
FileInputStream.close() method closes all channels supporting the connection.

Based on Java FIS API;

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close%28%29

Note: You are using a FileDescriptor and not a channel.

Comment: So when you say 'yes' you mean 'no'? Your second sentence isn't what he asked about.

Comment: If I look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/class-use/FileDescriptor.html I don't see that a channel can be obtained from a file descriptor. Are FileInputStream and FileOutputStream an umbrella for either file descriptor or channel, or implies a file descriptor also a channel? How would it answer what happens with the random access file?